# if few columns are the same and then append the row value together in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, pivot, pivot-table

The following are the details

**Here is the data frame**

> 

```
Name| Filename| delimetier| good delimeter| bad delimeter
A     123       48         a                A
A     123       48                          A
B     123       48         b                C
C     123       49         c                B
A     123       48         d                D
A     123       48         c                E
B     123       48         d                F
```

**What I want is**

> 

```
Name| Filename| delimetier| good delimeter| bad delimeter
A     123       48         a, c, d          A, D, E
B     123       48         b, d             C, F
C     123       49         c                B
```

**Even there have null value and duplicates, ignore them. And I have tried use groupby() to solve it, but failed.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `groupby.apply` to achieve this result.

Using this data:

```py
>>> df
  Name  Filename  delimeter good delimeter
0    A       123         48              a
1    B       123         48              b
2    C       123         49              c
3    A       123         48              d
4    A       123         48              c
5    B       123         48              d
```

Solution

```py
out = (
    df.groupby(['Name', 'Filename', 'delimeter'], as_index=False)
    ['good delimeter'].apply(', '.join)
)

print(out)
  Name  Filename  delimeter good delimeter
0    A       123         48        a, d, c
1    B       123         48           b, d
2    C       123         49              c
```